# Multiple values in single cell of .csv in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a .csv file in which I have 4 values. name,age,subject,gender. 
If i am giving single values for all then it is very easy using JMeter for e.g.:

> John,23,Maths,Male

But if I have to give for many subjects like e.g.:

> John,23,Maths:Science:History,Male

How could I achieve this using JMeter?

I have to pass this in XML request.

```
<name>John</name>
<age>23</age>
<subject>Maths:Science:History</subject>
<gender>Male</gender>
```

Comment: [Got the answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried already to do this using [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)?

Maybe I'm missing something in your issue but since you haven't to operate each subject separately you can read all the subjects list into the single variable and then refer they via this variable.

I.e. if you have to read entry from list like

```
...
John,23,Maths:Science:History,Male 
...
```

you can setup CSV Data Set Config in following way:

```
Filename = YOUR_CSV_FILE
File Encoding = 
Variable Names = vName,vAge,vSubjects,vGender
Delimiter = ,        // this is to delimit entries in list, not variables
```

and then use extracted values via variables:

```
<name>${vName}</name>
<age>${vAge}</age>
<subject>${vSubjects}</subject>
<gender>${vGender}</gender>
```

(since subjects are separated via ":" and variables - via "," - full subjects list will be extracted as one value).

Little guides for CSV Data Set Config usage [here](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) and [here](http://ivetetecedor.com/192/how-to-use-a-csv-file-with-jmeter).

**UPDATE 2012-04-19:**
Quick example to avoid unnecessary explanations and misunderstands.

[image]

- While Controller condition is `${__javaScript("${vName}"!="<EOF>",)}`.
- All the ":"-separated subject for each entry are extracted and stored as single variable - that's not a problem for CSV Data Set Config.

Comment: hi @alies thanks for the reply, yes you are right I missed the most important part, sorry for that.
I have to include subjects in .csv file like for eg: s1:s2:s3 and this subjects have to be converted to there keys like 1:2:3 from the response of sampler and pass to the request using single variable... ${vSubject}.. hope I am clear with all the points this time.

Comment: Hi. Sorry but it seems I not understand your comment. Please find update in answer above. Works fine for me. If it's not what you want than possibly amend your question and both input and output samples.

Comment: hi @alies thanks again, ok I will try to explain my best sample .csv row:   John,23,S1:s2:s3,Male                                               this s1:s2:s3 i will split and send to the request to retrieve keys for that respective subject from the response of the XML. that keys I will store in beanshell post processor and past to the other request for main result. Thanks.

Comment: @Shaggy, well, look into this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10244688/993246. Add additional beanshell sampler in example above with this code.