# How to read a string from .csv file and split it?

Tags: jmeter

I have a .csv file, from that I have to read a string and split it into substring, e.g.: `s1:s2:s3`.
Then I have to split it into `s1 s2 s3`.
Splitting based on ":".

Comment: hi @LaGrandMere I am using JMeter

Comment: From what I know, JMeter is a tool for testing performance. This csv file is a result you got from JMeter and you want to read and format it, whatever the language used ?

Comment: @LaGrandMere I am taking all the variables from .csv files for JMeter and it is not a response from JMeter, from that .csv I want to take a variable say ${subject} (s1:s2:s3) and I want to split that string to s1 s2 s3 and use that.

Comment: did you try the plugin ? I know you can define any kind of delimiters, but how did it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try the following beanshell (=java) code to parse extracted "subjects string" variable into separate "subject" variables (from [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) e.g.):

```java
String line = vars.get("vSubjects");

if(line != null) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ":");

    int i = 0;
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String subj = st.nextToken();

        i++;
        String varname = vars.get("vName") + "_subj_" + i;
        vars.put(varname,subj);
    }
}
```

So you'll get for each string parsed variables like the following (you can use [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to monitor):

```java
John_subj_1=Maths
John_subj_2=Science
John_subj_3=History
. . .
vAge=23
vGender=Male
vName=John
vSubjects=Maths:Science:History
```