# How to make JMeters access log sampler use timestamp for delay

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am using Jmeter's access log sampler to run a performance test. I am following the instructions [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_accesslog_sampler_step_by_step.html)

The only problem now is the fact I realized that the access log sampler does not make use of the timestamps in the access log to schedule the requests, it just goes through the entry one after the other.

As I would like to reproduce, as exactly as possible, the requests as they happen in the access log, I would require Jmeter to pace the requests based on the timestamps in the log entries.

So far, I have not figured how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is for you to analyze your data to determine the average arrival rate for the peak utilization period; and use this data to design your LT. This link might give you an idea how to do this: https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/apache/view-level-of-traffic-with-apache-access-log/

To generate requests with a random arrival rate I suggest you consider the Precise Throughput Timer https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer

Also, here is more information that:

[How to make jmeter do log replay based on time stamps present in access log lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739230/how-to-make-jmeter-do-log-replay-based-on-time-stamps-present-in-access-log-line?rq=1)